# Agrupando datatime no selec e somando os elementos da busca por dia para realizar uma comparação dos dias de um determinado mes

Tags: mysql, sql, dbeaver

Estou utilizando o type datatime e tentando realizar um select que faça a contagem de emissões dia-a-dia para montar um grafico de comparação dos dias de um determinado mes.

Porem ao agrupar as datas esta retornando os dias repetidos e somando somete as emissões de uma hora especifica de tal dia.

```
select count(solicitacao as emissões, dataSituacao
   from certificado
   where status like 'EMITIDO%'
   and dataSituacao BETWEEN '2020-10-01' and '2020-10-31'
   group by dataSituacao
   order by count(solicitacao) desc;
```

[image: Select e banco]

Answer (score -1):

Tente o seguinte:

```
select count(solicitacao) as emissões, DATE(dataSituacao) from certificado
where status like 'EMITIDO%' and DATE(dataSituacao)     
BETWEEN '2020-10-01' and '2020-10-31' group by DATE(dataSituacao) 
order by count(solicitacao) desc;
```

Answer (score -2):

Coloquei da seguinte maneira e deu certo, vlw demais!

`select count(solicitacao) as emissões, DATE(dataSituacao) from certificado where status like 'EMITIDO%' and DATE(dataSituacao)      BETWEEN '2020-10-01' and '2020-10-31' group by DATE(dataSituacao)  order by count(solicitacao) desc;`